# How to get rid of space between my dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

My application has 6 dropdowns 
[image: My dropdown screenshot]

This is the code for two of them,(note: i wrapped everything in container1 class,at the start of the code.

```
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-  expanded="true">
                Dropdown
                <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see i wrapped everything in a class called **container1**,it is made by be.
Here is what my class **container1** has

```
.container1 {
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

And it works like magic,this is what i get(as you see the space between them is smaller) [image: After putting everything into my custom css.]
Question: My method works well,but it is not responsive,when i make my browser screen smaller.This is what i get [image: What i get wit my method]

but if i leave it as it is with default bootstrap,with this big space between them,i get an awesome responsiveness.
[image: this is how it looks]

How would you make the space between dropdowns smaller,and in the same time leave the dropdown to remain responsive as bootstrap by default does,for small devices.

*Thank you for your time.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the responsivness comes from `.container1` class which decreases the width that `col-**-**` classes use. If you want your dropdown menus to be in the center of the `.row` div, use add `text-align: center;` in the `.row` div and remove the `margin-right: -15px;` and `margin-left: -15px;` from the `.row` (you can create custom class `.margin-ignore { margin: 0 !important; }` and add it to the `.row` div. Also, replace `col-xs-4` with `col-xs-6` because the dropdown buttons have bigger width that `col-xs-4` in some cases. The final result may look like this:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0n8xmy7a/2/

Try resize the screen and look does it fit for you. 

If you still does not like how and when the dropdown menus take their new position you can write your own column grid class and there write explicitly the width of screen when the class to trigger and the width of the elements that hold this class.

Good luck!

Comment: I just changed the text of the ,,dropdown'' to ,,Some random name" and see what happens,just try to resize it and you will see that the dropdown covers each other,like one on another https://jsfiddle.net/0n8xmy7a/3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead on using margins, you could use `max-width` to keep the buttons close together on large screens.

```
.container1 {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: it helped a bit,though the gaps a still big,i had to go with traditional way and instead of saying ,,Tech",i have to say "Tech&programming",to fill the space between the dropdowns.i hope there is a way to fix it.